# Deserializing an unknown object from Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, reverse

I've got an object that is serialized from a particular legacy program, there's little to no documentation on the type.

I'd like to extract the data into a readable structure into C#

I've tried:

- Opening the file in a hex editor and analysing the contents; they're garbled and not very clear
- Without much description and presumably compressed

What I know:

- What the file represents
- I can load changes in (provided I don't break any checksums or anything) into the legacy application
- It has been serialized by Ruby

Comment: `Is there a better way of approaching this then I am currently?` I can not understand your *way* to propose a *better* way. What have you tried? Why is it time consuming? What is the data? What is the format? No chance to read in c# directly?

Comment: Allow me to a bit more clear.

I've made various copies of this file and tried editing values one by one and finding their offsets in the file. However, some of the data gets very complicated; and has a lot of different variables. The data in question is data files for an RPG game. The format is as I said, a serialized Ruby structure or class after some some research - but other than that I'm not sure what it is.

I've been trying to rebuild the class in Ruby so I can serialize it back in.. and then save it out to a format I'd like. Maybe I can jsut read the binary stream raw, though.

Comment: Please see the golden rule [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: Considering I read it - and added more details I'm  not sure what the downvotes are for nor what I am missing.

Comment: Considering I read your question and really wanted to find a way to get the data in c#. Where is your data? Where should I start?

Comment: I was looking for general tips on reverse-engineering filetypes aside from using a hex editor. i.e: Documentation on Ruby structures (which there seems to be none)

Comment: OK. I hope you find an answer but it seems like an [XY-Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: I've made the question more concise.

Comment: You say `they're garbled and not very clear` but it may make sense for someone else who reads this question. This is why I always say "where is your data?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use C# to deserialize the file.  You should [unmarshal the data in a Ruby program](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html).  Your Ruby program can then emit it in a language neutral format (i.e. json, xml, etc.) that C# can easily read.

Comment: So my best bet is to find all the fields this Ruby class exposes, build a class out of them, and then attempt to demarshal it?

Comment: @Vaughan, That's my thought.  If you have access to the game which is creating the files, it's possible that the Ruby classes which are represented in the marshalled file are actually available to you.  If you can find those, the job gets much easier.